# 302 Found error message

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301, http-status-code-302

I have added a 301 redirect to the .htaccess of my Wordpress site but it's broken my site. It shows the following error message:

[see link](http://www.insurancetailors.co.uk/)

**.htaccess file**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^insurancetailors\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://insurancetailors.co.uk[R=301,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a space after the URL:

```
# here -----------------------------------------v
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://insurancetailors.co.uk [R=301,L]
```

Without the space, apache assumes you want to *302* redirect to the URL: `http://insurancetailors.co.uk[R=301,L]`, which is not what you want, and is infact, throwing a 500 server error. Without the `R=301` flag, apache assumes a *302* redirect.

---

EDIT:

Just to summarize comments:

> i want to redirect insurancetailor.com to insurancetailor.co.uk

The rule needs to look like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^insurancetailors\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://insurancetailors.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I've made the change and once I refresh the page it says 'this website has a direct loop'

Comment: @user3222864 Oh also, you probably want to fix the hostname: `insurancetailors.com` doesn't equal `insurancetailors.co.uk`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that...sorry!

Comment: @user3222864 `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^insurancetailors\.com$ [NC]` checks that the host isn't `.com`, but then you redirect to `http://insurancetailors.co.uk`, which doesn't end with `.com`, thus the redirect loop, you want to check that the host isn't the `.co.uk` version instead.

Comment: What is your intent with the redirect? Are you trying to get rid of any www. ? You need to be consistent with either .com or .co.uk -- they're two different domains.

Comment: i want to redirect insurancetailor.com to insurancetailor.co.uk

Comment: Their old site was built on .com but they uploaded their new site on .co.uk so they want their old site to point to the new .co.uk

Comment: @user3222864 "i want to redirect insurancetailor.com to insurancetailor.co.uk", then you want to remove the `!` in front of `^insurancetailors\.com$`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^insurancetailors\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://insurancetailors.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: I've made the change and once I refresh the page it says 'this website has a direct loop'

Comment: If you test this in a new browser it should work fine.